# Scraping a list of urls after log in

Tags: scrapy

The site to scrape has multiple projects with multiple pages and requires a log in. I tried:

```
def start_request(self):
    return [scrapy.FormRequest(, callback=self.logged_in)]

def logged_in(self, response):
    with open(...) as f:
        for url in f.readlines():
            return scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    ... do some scraping ...
    ... determine the url of the next page ...
    return scrapy.Request(... next page ..., self.parse)
```

This results in scraping **all pages** of **one project** (login is successful), but then it stops.

If `return scrapy.Request()` in function logged_in() is replaced by `yield scrapy.Request()` than it reads the **first page** of **all projects**.

I played around with the `return`s and `yield`s, but I can't get it to scrape **all pages** of **all projects**.

BTW I tried to create an array `start_uls`, but that doesn't work because it first needs to log into the site.

Comment: Are you sub-classing `Spider` or `CrawlSpider` or perhaps something else?  I assume you are inheriting from `scrapy.spiders.Spider`.

Comment: Indeed, I'm subclassing Spider.

Answer (score 1):

1. `return` will **always** return once, so don't expect more than one Request to be returned there, if you wish to return more than once, use `yield`
2. [Scrapy Requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) has a parameter called `dont_filter` that probably filter your calls to `parse` function

> dont_filter (boolean) – indicates that this request should not be filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to False.

Comment: I tried dont_filter in both requests, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. If I replace return by yield in the first Request (in logged_in()), then only the first page of every project is scraped.

Comment: @Guy is right; for sure you don't want a `return` in your `for` loop.  There are cases where this is the right thing to do, but yours is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

@Guy Gavriely makes a good point about `return`.  I would add that you need another parse method to filter all the pages you want:

```
def start_request(self):
    return [scrapy.FormRequest(, callback=self.logged_in)]

def logged_in(self, response):
    with open(...) as f:
        for url in f.readlines():
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    ... do some scraping ...
    yield scrapy.Request(... next page ..., self.parse_user)

def parse_user(self, response):
    ... do some scraping ....
    yield items
```

You're not done yet! The final parse method may need to be iterated for example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ... do some scraping ...
    for sel in (some_list_of_users_by_an_xpath):
        user_profile_tag = response.xpath('xpath_to_user_profile_urls')
        user_profile_url_clean = user_profile_tag(might need to clean prior to Request ie 'domain' + user_profile_tag or .split or .replace, etc.)
        yield scrapy.Request(user_profile_url_clean, self.parse_user)
```

In this case the parse function will parse a user every time in that list of users.  Then parse_user will do most of the actual digging and scraping.  Once it's done it will return to the original parse method and just go to the next one from the list.

Good luck!

Comment: I changed the returns to yields. In the parse() method of @liam a fixed set of urls to scrape is known on forehand. In the situation I'm encountering, the next url is scraped from the current page and used to get to the next page. I've edited the question to show this.
I can imagine that differentiating between parse and parse_user works in the case of a known number of user pages, but in my case I need to scrape data and determine the next url in the same function. I'm not sure how to translate this into a structure with two parse functions as the answer suggests.